# Trouble with strings and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, stdstring

My goal is to make a program that inputs a phone number and outputs it in a standard format. It skips over any non-number characters, will output if there are not enough digits, and will also skip over any digits after the first ten digits. My raptor worked without a hitch, but it's been difficult to translate it to C++.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio.
The problem is it is not running. If I put in anything more then one number in, I receive a fail error.

I am having some difficulty running this code.
Any and all help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void format(char outArray[], string inNumber)
{
    outArray[0] = '(';
    outArray[4] = ')';
    outArray[5] = ' ';
    outArray[9] = '-';

    outArray[1] = inNumber[0];
    outArray[2] = inNumber[1];
    outArray[3] = inNumber[2];
    outArray[6] = inNumber[3];
    outArray[7] = inNumber[4];
    outArray[8] = inNumber[5];
    outArray[10] = inNumber[6];
    outArray[11] = inNumber[7];
    outArray[12] = inNumber[8];
    outArray[13] = inNumber[9];
}

int main()
{
    string phone, inNumber;
    cout << "Please enter a phone number: ";
    cin >> phone;
    int index = 0;
    int num = 0;
    char outArray[14];

    for (index; phone[index] >= '0' && phone[index] <= '9'; index++)
    {
        inNumber[num] = phone[index];
        num++;
    }

    if (inNumber.size() > 10)
    {
        format(outArray, inNumber);

        cout << "The properly formatted number is: ";
        cout << outArray;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Input must contain at least 10 digits." << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific on what difficulties you're encountering.

Comment: You outputted the wrong thing and your first for loop never checks if you reached the end of the input.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I fixed the output to "cout << outArray;".
I will update my post as I fix mistakes.
How would I go about adding in a check to fix the loop?

Comment: `inNumber` is never allocated any storage, so `inNumber[num]` cannot be used. Perhaps `inNumber.push_back` is a better choice. Unrelated: `for (index; phone[index] >= '0' && phone[index] <= '9'; index++)` could be `for ( ; !std::isdigit(phone[index]); index++)`. It will exit as soon as it finds a non-digit,  but I'm not 100% certain this is what you are wanting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to note:

- Use `std::string` instead array of `char` array.
- You do not need to check charters using a for loop unless you are not sure about the input(`phone`). However, if that's the case, use `std::getline()` to get the input and parse as follows using a *[range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)*.
- You can use [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) to check the `char`acter is a digit.

  > My goal is to make a program that inputs a phone number and outputs it
  > in a standard format. It skips over any non-number characters, will
  > output if there are not enough digits, and will also skip over any
  > digits after the first ten digits.
- That means the number should have a minimum length of `10`. Then the
  `if` statement should be `if (inNumber.size() >= 10)`
- Need a pass by ref call in the function `format()`, since you want to change the content of `outArray`. Additionally, `inNumber` could be a
  *`const` ref*, since we do not change this string.

Updated code: **([See a sample code online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BXZ2Hk8rvCZlvwNY))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>   // std::isdigit, std::size_t

void format(std::string& outArray, const std::string& inNumber) /* noexcept */
{
   for (std::size_t index = 0; index < 10; ++index)
   {
      if (index == 0) outArray += '(';
      else if (index == 3) outArray += ") ";
      else if (index == 6) outArray += '-';
      outArray += inNumber[index];
   }
}

int main()
{
   std::string phone;
   std::cout << "Please enter a phone number: ";
   std::getline(std::cin, phone);

   std::string inNumber;

   for (char letter : phone)
      if (std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(letter))) // check the letter == digits
         inNumber += letter;


   if (inNumber.size() >= 10)
   {
      std::string outArray;
      format(outArray, inNumber);
      std::cout << "The properly formatted number is: ";
      std::cout << outArray;
   }
   else {
      std::cout << "Input must contain at least 10 digits." << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 inNumber[num] = phone[index]; //undefined behavior.
```

You cannot subscript `inNumber` now, since its capacity is 0, thus it can not **store** or **access** any element here.

You may need to use `string`'s constructor whose parameter has a `size_t` type or `string::reserve` or `string::resize`.

And I'm happy to see cppreference get more complete now, learn to use it:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

BTW, this function won't do anything you want to:

```
void format(char outArray[], string inNumber)
```

maybe you'd like to have an signature like this?

```
void format(char outArray[], string& inNumber)
```